# Android in-game pause screen

Tags: android

Right now Im calling a new activity with an xml-view when I pause my game, but Since I do this I need to use `context` in my real-time code, and this is causing a memory leak. Is there any preffered way to pause the game? By pause I mean if game is over, if I die, or if I press pause-button. Would a custom dialog work just aswell? this would mean I wont have to leave my main-activity while im in-game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **startActivityForResult**, that works fine and it does not need passing the context. But in my games I've created a game object which looks like and behaves like a dialog and simply activate it on pause or game over, thus never create other activity or Android dialog.

EDIT
An example using Options, which some say is safer in order to avoid out of memory errors:

```
private Bitmap loadBitmap(int resourceID){
            Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false; 
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; 
            Bitmap tempBmp = null;
            try{
                tempBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(resourceID)), null, options);
            }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){

            }catch (Error e){

            }
            return tempBmp;
}
```

Comment: ok, I think Ill go with a dialog, Same thing as having a game object like you have, the main thing is to not leave my activity, since that causes a leak

Comment: It may not be a leak but when an activity is on pause Android may delete the big bitmaps and other resorces used in there. Check my question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35434/how-to-handle-loading-and-keeping-many-bitmaps-in-an-android-2d-game

Comment: `getHolder().setFormat(0x00000004); //RGB_565` load bitmpas with
 `options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;` this is pretty interesting. Heard some stuff about this but didt know how to implement it. where do I put these 2 lines? can you update answer and tell?

Comment: I load bitmaps like this `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResources(R.drawable.image);` so where do I put the `options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;` if I load them like this?

Comment: See the example I posted. Some say that to use decodeStream is safer... resourceId = R.drawable.something

Comment: nice, thanks! So to use this to load for example an image called "ball" Id just write `bitmap = loadBitmap(R.drawable.ball);` ? and one last qustion, why do u use `inScaled = false`? Hopefully this can reduce my heap-size a bit aswell :)

Comment: Yes, that is the way. inScaled = false is to prevent Android resizing the bitmap according to its screen density etc. You can take the control of the bitmap size by using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() so there is no surprises...

Comment: I want it to resize tho, since Im downscaling all my images from xhdpi. cant have xhdpi-size on a mhdpi-phone ^^ Well ty for ur help! hopefully this will help me heap-size since Im having some issues with it, wont be able to try until 2morrow! :)

Comment: Hi again! hopefully you can answer this! I tried ur method and it works great, almost cut my heap in half :) But there is a problem with using `decodeStream`, when I load my images with it some get smaller then they were before(on screen), but if I use `decodeRecourse` instead it works fine. do u know why this is?

Comment: It also cant load all my images, my enemy-image wont get loaded for example, nor will my joystick-bg with opacity, or my red bullets, do you know why? does it have to do with the colors?